# AngularJS testing error: Unknown provider: $_httpBackend_Provider <- $_httpBackend_

Tags: jasmine, angularjs

I am attempting to test an AngularJS controller with a Jasmine unit test spec file. My approach is to use $httpBacked, in the following test:

```
describe('SubmissionsController', function() {
    var minimal_mock_response = [ { id: 1 } ]; 
    var scope, routeParams, $httpBackend; 

    beforeEach(module('submissionServices'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($_httpBackend_, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();  
        $httpBackend = $_httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/submissions').respond(minimal_mock_response);
        routeParams = {};
    }));

    it('passes a trivial test', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

I inserted the expect(true).toBe(true) just to get the test to execute and fail, even though it does not touch the angular controller. When I I attempt to run the test with jasmine-headless-webkit, I receive the following error:

```
jasmine-headless-webkit spec/javascripts/SubmissionsControllerSpec.js

Running Jasmine specs...
F
FAIL: 1 test, 1 failure, 0.011 secs.

Submissions controllers SubmissionsController passes a trivial test.     (XXX/spec/javascripts/SubmissionsControllerSpec.js:18)
Error: Unknown provider: $_httpBackend_Provider <- $_httpBackend_

Test ordering seed: --seed 9254
```

**Are there any hints on how I can correct this error and make the trivial test execute?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you're injecting the wrong service. It doesn't know what `$_httpBackend_` is. You should be able to just do this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();  
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/submissions').respond(minimal_mock_response);
    routeParams = {};
}));
```

If you want to get a reference to the `$httpBackend` service once and store that as `$httpBackend`, [ghiden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262157/1014979) is the way to go.

Comment: The only issue here was a typo. It should have been \_$httpBackend\_, not $_httpBackend_. The answer below is preferable to this one.

Comment: @RichardMorgan You're right. I've updated my answer. +1 to ghiden

Comment: Yes, angular injector strips away _ in _$httpBackend_, and you want to have it _$httpBackend_ if you want to have variable availalbe at describe level with the same name

Answer (score 30):

Enclosing service names with underscores has some benefit.

From your code, I can see that you probably wanted to save the reference to $httpBackend. This is how you wanted to do. The placement of underscore was one off.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();  
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    ...
```

Angular is smart enough to remove underscores and returns $httpBackend back to you, and you can save it to your own $httpBackend.

Comment: This is the answer that should be marked as correct, or else you wont be able to use the service by the familiar name "$httpBackend" inside your tests.